# Generating sample data in a function in r without repeat

Tags: r, random

I have the following reproducible code:

```
x <- as.data.table(c(1:20))
samplefunction <- function(x) { 
if(x <= 10 ) { 
sample(35:45)
}else if(x > 10) { 
sample(50:60)
}
}

day1 <- x[,sales := sapply(x, samplefunction)]
day2 <- x[,sales := sapply(x, samplefunction)]
```

Both day1 and day2 populate the sample value for sales. It looks like the value returned from samplefunction is re-used for each iteration. How can I create seperate data frames (day1, day2,...) and re-generate random data for the sales column each time? Set.Seed() is used to re-use the same random generation..I'm looking for the opposite, in a sense. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you mean to `sample(35:45, 1)` and `sample(50:60, 1)` in your sample function? But you're being caught by data.table's 'reference' semantics, whereas you're used to R's 'copy-on-change' semantics -- day1 and day2 both reference the same data.table x, so when you update sales for day2, you update day1. If you'd used a standard data frame (you'd need `library(data.table)` for your example to be reproducible!), you'd see that you are actually generating two separate sequences and that day1 and day2 are actually different.

Comment: I find it easier to add columns to a data.table by sapplying a function to a seperate column using the := operator. Is there an easy way to do this within a dataframe? If so, I could change the syntax to just use data.frames and remove the reference to data.tables.

Comment: day1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, sales=sample(35:45)); day2 <- data.frame(x=11:20, sales=sample(50:60))